# Smooth movements for anchor links with absolute path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the following jQuery to give [my links](http://versacreative.com.php53-9.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/) (top menu bar) a smooth movement once they are clicked on.

This works fine when the link is `<a href="#services">link</a>`; however, it does not work once the full address is prepended to the hash tag `<a href="http://domain.com#services">link</a>`.

I have to use the absolute path so when the links are clicked from internal pages, they still bring you back to the homepage and the right location.

```
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash,
            $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
```

Any idea on how to modify that code so it works on links with absolute paths?

Comment: Then what you would have to do is to prevent the newly loaded page from scrolling to the targeted anchor, and then animate it to the correct position appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a selector, that in my opinion is crazy, add a class like `.anchor-link` or something to all of the links you want to animate.

Then update your code to

```
  $('.anchor-link').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash,
            $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
```

Comment: But this still wouldn't work if somebody is on an internal page (`http://domain.com/internal.html`) and clicks on (`http://domain.com#services`) to go back to homepage, would it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here. Changing the jquery selector to a class instead of only targeting anchor a links, would make the code you posted work on any link that has that class. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I agree on changing the selector to a class; however, if somebody clicks on `http://domain.com#services` from an internal page to go back to homepage, they are not really "clicking" on the link, so the the jQuery "click" event will not be fired (because the page has reloaded). Does that make sense?

Comment: @farjam are you saying you want that animation to occur for external links?

Comment: @mituw16 the code you are proposing (which is similar to mine except for the different type of selector) currently does not work on my website. It does not give the links a smooth transition once they are clicked on.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use jQuery for this nor do I think jQuery animations would yield the best results. You can do this all in css3 and have more control over the animation. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aX5ak/) of something similar to what you are trying to do. As you can see you just set the id of the `div` and then use somthing like this:

```
#home:target ~ #header #navigation #link-home,
#portfolio:target ~ #header #navigation #link-portfolio,
#about:target ~ #header #navigation #link-about,
#contact:target ~ #header #navigation #link-contact{
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

To let the css know you are targeting that specific div when you click on the nav button. Then you use css3 transition

```
 -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
```

To animate the div as you want.